# Is it okay to put a 2U server in a 2-post rack?

Tags: dell, rack

I have a Dell R710 2U server.  It's pretty heavy, so it seems to me like it needs support in the front and the back, but we only have a 2-post rack.  The rack is bolted to the floor, so it's pretty sturdy.

In general, is it okay to flush-mount a 2U server in a 2-post rack?

I have a much lighter 1U server mounted there, and it seems okay.  Also, the [tech guide](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-r710-tech-guidebook.pdf) for the R710 says:

> Support for flush and center mount installation in CEA-310-E compliant 2-post racks (1U & 2U only)

But it just doesn't seem right to me.

Thanks!

**Update:** I contacted Dell tech support, and they pointed me to a [3rd party solution from racksolutions.com](http://www.racksolutions.com/dell-servers-in-relay-racks-centered.shtml) for center-mounting the R170 in a relay rack.  So I'll try that + one of the [shelves](http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/Rackmount_Shelves_2%20Point.asp) suggested by Zypher.

Comment: +1 Would be interested in this answer. Seems like a great deal of weight on the front. What hardware came with the R710? Any I have seen is for 4 post

Comment: I hear the guy who invented the two post rack is brothers with the guy who invented the short handled shovel.

Comment: Dave: Yep, the hardware is for a 4-post rack.

Comment: I've used the racksolutions.com rails to mount servers as big as 5U (PowerEdge 2600) in two-post racks with no problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I'd be comfortable doing that either. We use Two post [Rack Shelves](http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/Rackmount_Shelves_2%20Point.asp) to help support 2-4U server in 2 post racks.

Answer (score 6):

If it was me I would not flush mount a server in a 2 post rack I would center mount all my servers. I don't like to put servers in a Relay rack as they are built more for telco and network equipment. They will work for servers as the mounding brackets have been manufactured to work with the Relay racks. But in general I don't like to use relay racks to mount servers.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, and the manual said that it is supported in a CEA-310-E compliant 2-post rack, then I would verify that my rack meets the compliance and call Dell to find out what mounting hardware to use.

Comment: I tried to look up the standard, but it costs $52!  Sheesh.  http://www.ce.org/Standards/StandardDetails.aspx?Id=2470&number=CEA-310-E

Comment: Why not contact the vendor of the rack and ask them if it meets the compliance. Also, are there any compliance stickers anywhere on the rack or any identifying labels, etc.?

Comment: Those are good suggestions!  We got the rack free (second hand), and it doesn't appear to be branded, but I'll look more closely.

Answer (score 2):

If you can center mount it, it should be fine. I wouldn't flush mount it due to the amount of torque that will be put on the mounting hardware from the rear end of the server just dangling in space.